# Best design for delay of processing queue elements (multithreaded)

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, design-patterns, queue

I have a blocking queue of responses which need to be processed about 10 minutes after they were added by another thread. Each element have a timestamp field. I was wondering if there's a better solution than this one:

P1 is throwing elements few times per second, when P1 adds an element to the queue it signals it.

P2 receives a signal, checks the first (top) element of the queue and sleeps till this element is ready to be processed. Kind of FIFO.

P2 wakes, process the element and repeats till the queue is empty, then waits for signal again.

Comment: If P2 can process the elements in its incoming queue in the order they are put into the queue (but not immediately), then there's no reason to do anything more complicated (that I can think of).

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems ok, but I would make it in async manner.

In example check every minute what you have in queue and process everything you can.